# How to calcule string of column datagridview2?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview 2. the field is  R, G, B, Textur, Kebenaran.
The value of Kebenaran is Benar or Salah.
example:This is my datagridview2

```
R     G     B     Textur    Kebenaran
100   100   100   200       Benar    
120   90    110   240       Salah
90    50    100   300       Benar
```

I want to calculate count how many Benar in the Kebenaran. And displayed in Texbox.
Using C# 2015

Comment: what's did you try ?

Comment: What is c# 2015?

Answer (score 0):

```
((DataTable)datagridview2.DataSource).Select("Kebenaran='Benar'").Length;
```

but again since question does not contain complete information, this answer has it's own assumptions.